# Gitlab Pages Tab doesn't appear

Tags: web, gitlab, github-pages, docusaurus

I'm trying to deploy a static docusaurus website with gitlab pages but the "Pages" tab (which should be in "Deploy" tab) doesn't appear.

Here's my CI file :

```
  image: $my_docker_image$

  stages:
    - test
    - deploy

  test:
    stage: test
    script:
      - cd website
      - npm install --force
      - npm run build
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

  pages:
    stage: deploy
    script:
      - cd website
      - npm install --force
      - npm run build
      - mv ./build ../public
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - public
    only:
      - deployement
```

It's my first time using this feature

Comment: Maybe just caused by a typo?  "deployement" should be "deployment"